# Should in-character questions be deleted?

Tags: discussion

So, I just had the following happen:

I posted a riddle, written completly in-character (https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/26016). It got downvotes due to in the title referring to "stupid-ass-dc".

The riddle's awnser was Deadpool. Deadpool is a character whose personality is interesting because not only he's an antihero, who is an insultuous loudmouth, from Marvel, but he is also **constantly** breaking the fourth wall.

Everything in the original post was in character, and that fact was even hinted at during the main body of the question.

Essentially, I had a riddle written in-character, following known character's manerisms and ticks deleted, because people did not read or did not figure out the awnser. Here's the full riddle:

> **I'm like Kelly Clarkson** - "What doesn't kill me makes me stronger" is a song by Clarkson. Likewise, Deadpool has cancer, but the mutation which gives him his power is spread with the cancer, making the cancer (and other things) unable to kill him, because he essentially regenerates faster than the cancer kills him
>
> **I look like I was beat by Chris Brown** - Once again, Dark Humour, this time referring to having a black eye. Two in fact. [image: Notice the eyes on his suit]
>
> **Even my pens come in double** - He carries a sword, well, two swords. Some say the pen is mightier than the sword, he...doesn't
>
> **Even the title is an hint** - By having an insultuous title to the rival company, the character affirms that he is part of Marvel, rather than DC. Once again, completly in character with Deadpool
>
> **Because on a pyramid house I'm forced to live** - Traditionally, houses and rooms are represented has having 4 walls. However, since deadpool often breaks the 4th wall, this hint refers to that, as if he lives in an house with 3 walls (pyramidal), it's because he broke the 4th.

I couldn't find any guideline nor rule against having in-character questions and riddles, so why isn't this riddle allowed?

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the original riddle, it seems pretty clear that it wasn't closed for being in-character, but rather for being "offensive":

> This question was marked as spam or offensive and is therefore not shown - you can see the revision history for details.

I assume that this is either due to the use of the word ***ass*** (which seems pretty benign in my mind), or due to the fact that it is demeaning a specific entity (DC comics).

My suspicion is that if you had made the "stupid-ass-DC" comment in the question instead of in the title, people wouldn't have cared that much, or might even have been more apt to recognize that the comment was being made in-character.  But when everyone sees it pop up in the list of questions, it's probably much more likely to attract negative attention.

Short answer:  people probably jumped the gun, and closed the question for what looked like immature name-calling, when it was in fact part of the puzzle.  You can always request to re-open the question if you think a mistake was made.

Comment: Just for the record, my comment on the OP was the reason for my downvote (though I didn't vote to close it). I have nothing against "in-character" riddles, and this one, imho, would have been fine without the one part I (and, it seems, others) took issue with.

Comment: Yeah, I'm just gonna, clear the offensive flags on that. That was, actually, my bad. I would... _still_ recommend editing the question, though.